# Fire a function when a user close the website or inactive in django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am coding a Django website, in which some files are downloaded and shown to the user. Right now I want to know how to delete all these files if a user close the website or inactive for a certain amount of time(Can django time every connection from the user and know if inactive?).

So basically I want to know how to call a function in view.py if my Django website is closed/inactive.

Comment: What you mean in term ```closed/inactive```, you mean when client close browser or tab ?

Comment: Yes. If a user close the webpage

Comment: Mostly this is ```Javascript``` related question and not django. For example ```Javascript``` support ```onunload``` method, implement it when when ```onunload``` will be called, make ```AJAX``` call on your **Django View**.

Comment: I tried, but is seems not working on my Chrome browser. And I want to know if Django can manage the connections from the users. The server should know all connections with different users right? Is it possible to call a function in the server side if one connection is inactive?

Comment: I strongly believe that this is not possible from **Django** point of view. There are a lot of hacks in **javascript**, which will be adopted on chrome (of course, also). Check it.

Comment: You could have a look into websockets: open one when someone visits the page. If a websocket is closed then you know someone left the page. But like the others say: most of the work is done in JavaScript. For the websockets part have a look at [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).